# i18next strange behavior with requirejs, backbone and underscore templates

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, i18next

I'm using i18next and I think it's great.
I'm using it in conjuction with Backbone and Underscore templates.
Let me explain my situation.
As soon as the application kicks in, I init i18n and then I start Backbone history, so I'm pretty sure that i18n is ready when the application is started.

```
var option = {
    debug: true
};

i18n.init(option).done(function()
{
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Everything works fine because when I need to render my view, I just call a method and inside that method i do:

```
$("body").i18n();
```

I see everthing perfectly localized!

The problem is with views that render themselves and after data has been fetched from the server need to re-render. In that case, on that controls, localized text disappears. If I block the 2nd rendering when data is ready, everything is perfectly localized. Otherwise (even if I remove the first rendering when data is not ready yet), data doesn't appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

You have to call i18n also when views are rendered. See this question for more details: [i18next - brunch and backbone setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676278/i18next-brunch-and-backbone-setup/17678413#17678413)

Comment: Thanks drax for your reply. That is what I did, but it doesn't seem to work. The strange fact is that if I do like this:

    $(template).i18n();

it works the first time, but not when the view is refreshed. 

While if I do like:

   $(".view-class").i18n();

where .view-class is a specific class linked to that view, it works!
So strange...

Comment: could you post code of view? without that, it is very difficult to find out where the problem might be